# i want to store restaurant id when saving my review blade

Tags: laravel

I have created a review blade for restaurants i need it to save the restaurants id .i have a variable called restaurant_id which stores the restaurants review comment.This is my review blade

```
<html>
 {!!Form::open(['action' =['ReviewsController@store'],'method'=>'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'])!!}
    <div class="form-group"> 

    {{Form::textarea('value',null,['id'=>'value','placeholder'=>'Insert 
    here','name'=>'value'])}}
    </div>
    {{Form::submit('submit',['class'=>'btn btn- 
    primary','type'=>'submit','id'=>'submit'])}}
    {!!Form::close()!!}


     </html>
```

i also have user_id which stores the id the currently logged in user but it gives me an error 
**ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object**
This is the review controller function that stores the review

```
public function store(Request $request )
    {


 // $restaurant=Restaurant::find($id);
    $review=new Review;
    $review->user_id=auth()->user()->id;
    $review->restaurant_id=$request->route('id');
    $review->value=$request->input('value');
    $review->save();
    }
```

This is the link to the review blade template on the restaurant

```
<a href="{{ route('restaurants.review',$restaurant->id)}}">Add review</a>
```

Comment: Which line gives you that error? If it's `$review->user_id=auth()->user()->id`, consider what happens when there's not a user logged in currently.

Comment: yes its that one

Answer (score 0):

```
$review->user_id=auth()->user()->id;
```

This line assumes the existence of a logged in user. If your application supports reviews from non-authenticated users, you need to account for `auth()->user()` being null instead of a User object:

```
$review->user_id = auth()->user() ? auth()->user()->id : null;
```

Comment: i have implemented your code and it gives me SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `reviews` (`user_id`, `restaurant_id`, `value`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, jkdccjknsd jjjj, 2019-07-10 18:56:36, 2019-07-10 18:56:36))

Comment: @MatildahMariwa Then you need to make your `user_id` `nullable` in the migrations, **or** prevent non-logged-in users from posting reviews. Giovanni's answer gives a way of doing the latter, although I'd use [the built-in authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization) personally.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, specifically:

`auth()->user()->id;`

is assuming there is always an authenticated user. Currently there isn't, therefore you are:

`Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

since `auth()->user()` is a non-object and you're attempting to get the property `id` from it.

You will have to do some kind of authentication check assuming you only want authenticated users doing what you want done.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (! Auth::check() {
        // Do something here if the user isn't authenticated, such as
        // return back()->withInput();
    }

    $review = new Review;
    $review->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $review->restaurant_id = $request->route('id');
    $review->value=$request->input('value');
    $review->save();
}
```

Comment: okay changed the code now am getting the errorSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'restaurant_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `reviews` (`user_id`, `restaurant_id`, `value`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, ?, xkkx;xx, 2019-07-10 21:26:20, 2019-07-10 21:26:20))

Comment: $request->route('id'); is null, check your request

Comment: sorry am not getting.Which request

Comment: $request... specifically $request->route('id'); ```Column 'restaurant_id' cannot be null``` is a dead giveaway that it's null so check it and find out why. Without seeing any more of the code there is no way for me to tell but if i were to guess it's a route model binding issue  or something similar. Try too dd($request) and see what you have after submitting.